# dompdf Kannada Character encoding not rendering in codeigniter php

Tags: php

actually am using dompdf along with codeigniter php, in loading of dompdf not rendering kannada characters but it displays empty. and it displays only english characters

```
**here is my controller**



function uc_format_Print()
{
$pdf_data['uc_format_pdf']=$this->Insert_model->fetch_uc_format();
$this->load->view('pdfucformat',$pdf_data);
$html = $this->output->get_output();// Get output html
$this->load->library('pdf');// Load pdf library
$this->dompdf->loadHtml($html,'UTF-8');// Load HTML content
$this->dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$this->dompdf->render();// Render the HTML as PDF
$this->dompdf->stream("pdfucformat.pdf", array("Attachment"=>0));// Output the generated PDF (1 = download and 0 = preview)
 }

**this is my model**
public function fetch_uc_format()
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_ucformat');
$this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean Canada? And if so, which character encoding are you missing? Can you give an example of what you get, and what you expect, etc.

Comment: not canada its kannada indian language, utf8mb4_unicode_ci is stored in database but its not fetching as well